# Trying to implement alternative to "position:sticky" with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to element with class "navigation" stick to the left corner of viewport and stay there until the parent section with class "three" not been scrolled. But I can't make it follow the left edge of the viewport smoothly, it constantly twitches and falls outside the screen when scrolling, and I can't get it why? I have a lack of JS knowledge, just learning, help me please to understand if it does not bother you.

P.S. No "position:fixed" or "position:sticky" - I can't use it, just pure JavaScript.

My CodePen: https://codepen.io/RaizRus/pen/eYpXyOB

If you don't like codepen for some reasons:

```js
function stickyHeader(event) {
  var head = document.getElementById("header-trigger").getBoundingClientRect().left;

        var x = Math.abs(head);
    
        if (x > 0) {
            document.getElementById("header").style.transform = `translate3d(${Math.abs(head)}px, 0px, 0px)`;
        }
}
```

```css
.slide {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 400vw;
}
.one {
    background: #efdefe;
}
.two {

}
.three {
    background: #EFF2F3;
}
.four {
    background: #00dfdf;
}
.wrapper {

    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
.outer-wrapper {
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vw;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /*Soverflow-x: hidden; */
    position: absolute;
}
.outer-wrapper {

    scrollbar-width: none;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display:none;
} 

.navigation {
  width:20vw;
  background-color: #2B3A42;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.navigation li a {
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <div id="scroll-container" class="outer-wrapper scroll-container">
    <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
      <div id="header-trigger" class="slide three" onwheel="stickyHeader(event)">
            <header id="header" class="navigation">
                <div class="navigation__content">
                    <p class="navigation__desc">
                      Title <strong>about something</strong>
                  </p>
                    <ul class="navigation__links">
                        <li><a href="#one">Water</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#two">Illusions</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#three">Shine</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="#four">Flowers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <p class="about_text">
                      Little bit more text
                    </p>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```